# Should ARM Template be ran on every deployment

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

When using template to deploy infrastructure.Is it expected to run your arm template on every deployment or are you suppose run the arm template once to setup infrastructure and create a another pipeline that deploy to the infrastructure that was setup by ARM.

Run ARM -> Once,
deploy build artifacts -> Repeat

Run ARM then deploy build artifacts  -> Repeat

Answer (score 2):

Depends how you want to setup your test environments. In my system I deploy each branch to a new test environment, instead of using a single instance of a resource as "test" instance and deploy to that. So I do run ARM template deployments as part of the deployment pipeline. I place the deployment scripts and ARM templates for a microservice in the same repository as the code. This makes the coherence I am looking for as infra, backend, frontend all live together in one repository for a microservice.

Comment: Why did someone -1 my answer? please leave a comment

Comment: somebody downvoted mine as well :) angry kid I guess

Comment: I just upvoted both of you guys answers because it was very helpful because previously, I have no idea how to go about building a pipeline for arm template. I guess the question is too open ended that is why somebody decided to give us all a down vote.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to throw an opinion for the other side.  I highly recommend rerunning your ARM infrastructure deployments every release or at least setting up a scheduled deployment. The reason being, yes it may take a little more time...or a few extra minutes depending on your resources. However, in larger organizations and in particular in lower environments where developers or others may have at least contributor access, there is the risk of drift. By rerunning the ARM templates for each deployment you are guaranteeing the state matches your template, without having to add or setup any policy logic.

Plus I'd say it's the ultimate confidence in your Infrastructure as code. You are 100% confident your template is rerunable.

Answer (score 0):

well, there is no answer to this one, but in my book it doesnt make sense to run the arm template if there are no changes to it. you should have a separate repo for IaC code or a separate build for arm template

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, re-running the arm template depends on whether your project’s infrastructure and configuration are updated.

If the structure and configuration of the project you build is not updated, you do not need to run the arm template multiple times. You could directly deploy the build artifacts to the same resource.

On the other hand, if your project requires new resources or parameters, you can update or create new resources by editing the Template configuration file (generally a json file).  This allows the deployed environment to meet the needs of your project.

In short, there is no absolute answer to this topic, it only depends on your needs.

Comment: would it hurt to run it every time?
it seems to me it will be appropriate to run it every time in other to prevent lag between prod and dev because if there is no update then the state will always be the same.

Comment: I think it won't hurt. It also makes sense to run the ARM template in combination with CI/CD. Maybe [this blog](https://platform.deloitte.com.au/articles/arm-template-lifecycle-management-dos-and-donts) could give you some ideas.